# How can I use regex to capture this certain range of ages?

Tags: regex

I have a set of age data, like below;

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
1,1
1,2
1,3
2,12
11,13,15
7,8,12
```

And so on...  I am trying to use Regex in to target a certain set of ages between 1-7, but only when a child older than 8 is not in the group.

```
(?![8-9]|1[0-7]$)\b[1-7]\b
```

My current matches include all single digit lines 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 - perfect. It matches 1,2 and 1,3 for example - perfect. However, it also matches the line with 2,12 and 7,8,12 - not what I wanted.

Any advice would be appreciated on how to resolve?  Thanks in advance, I am continuing to try to correct.

Comment: I would capture the numbers separately with regexp and then deal with the logical side of the problem with another language.

Comment: @AdrienBrunelat – ...or without programming: load it as comma separated data into Excel (menu Data > From Text) and create necessary formulas there.

Comment: @miroxlav using excel formulas *is* [programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_programming)..

Comment: @Aprillion – sure, if you want it this way, then maybe even setting up Outlook mail rule is programming :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put it in a group and repeat it:

```
^(?:[^\n\d]*\b[1-7]\b[^\n\d]*)+$
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/xJ6eQ0/1).

---

Broken down, this says:

```
^        # anchor it to the beginning
(?:      # a non capturing group
[^\n\d]* # not a number or newline
\b       # a word boundary
[1-7]    # a digit from 1-7
\b       # another boundary
[^\n\d]* # same as above
)+       # repeat the whole construct at least once
$        # THE END
```

---

Or as others said, `explode()` it on the comma and compare it programatically.

Comment: this is perfect, thanks Jan. I have one last question, and I am trying to do myself but just getting nowhere.  I will create one last question!  Thank you kindly!

Comment: @PhilBarnes: Glad to help, I'm looking forward to the next question :)

Comment: But if suddenly your requirements change from age 7 to age 10 or more, this will become obsolete.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
^([1-7]{1}(,|$))*$
```

You also can exclude strings with `,` ending:

```
^([1-7]{1}(,(?=[1-7])|$))*$
```